# Как сделать кнопку скачивания видео с плеера

Tags: html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать кнопку скачивания видео с плеера, как на этом рисунке

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="*ссылка на источник*" download="download">Скачать видео</a>
```

Работает не во всех браузер, порой просто открывает видео, но оттуда его уже можно будет скачать. Если нужно, то внутри `a` можно вместо текста вставить `<button>Скачать видео</button>`, чтобы обернуть это в кнопку

Comment: `download="download"` - это дичь какая-то... Или просто `download`, или `download="имя файла.mp4"` И button'у внутри ссылке делать нечего.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<video controls width="250">
  <source src="https://v7.cdnpk.net/videvo_files/video/partners0499/large_watermarked/he1e2fc69_3121560_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```